# PySocksを用いて、Tor経由でのWebスクレイビング

Tags: python, websocket, socket

PySocksを用いてurllib2モジュールでの通信にTorを経由させて、匿名性を持たせようてしています。
ただ、ある関数(urllib2を用いている)を実行するときだけTorを経由しないようにしたいのですがどうすれば良いのでしょうか？
urllib2.socket.socketを初期化して元のTorを経由しない通信に戻すことはできるのでしょうか？
ご指導よろしくお願いします。

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9050)
urllib2.socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
original_socket = socket.socket
...
socks.setdefaultproxy(...)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
...
socket.socket = original_socket
urllib2.a_function()
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

元の `socket.socket` を保存しておき、必要に応じてセットし直せばいいだけです。プログラムの作りによっては、`try` ~ `finally` で囲って、例外が発生しても確実に切り替わるようにした方がいいかもしれません。